# Is Ionic 3 lazy loading good approach for big applications?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am going to start with a ionic 3 project.

My application is a enterprise level application.As per ionic documents, I come to know that Ionic 3 lazy loading decreases start time of the aplication but for such big application, Is Lazy loading a good approach? Can it cause any problem in future?

Answer (score 0):

One most important advantage of lazy loading in ionic is that it divides the app into different modules which makes the app modular and maintainable.

It also eliminates the unnecessary page imports which make the code cleaner.
It definitely decreases the startup time and improves the app performance.

Comment: is it best practice to include/add ionic native plugin in specific page  module in provider instead app module?